# InfoPath Data Connection Email

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, infopath, sql-server, infopath-data-connections

Working in InfoPath 2013.
Background -  I have a InfoPath form connected to a SP List.  When the form is submitted an notification is sent.  The notification email is sent from InfoPath that was created using a Data Connection.  In the notification email there is a preface and body.  The body looks to have a table created in InfoPath.

Problem - I want to modify the data that appears in the notification email. Easy? Nope.  I go to the data connection and modify.  I can only modify the preface not the data that appears in the table.  Mind you that data in the table is fixed not being pulled from the information entered into SharePoint.  This may be a "ignorant" question How do I locate the information in the table to modify if it is not found under Data Connections then Modify?  Are the fields being pulled into the table? Is it an SQL table?  I am lost and hope someone can help.

Solutions - I looked in the field properties and checked if Rules were created.  I do not notice anything out of the ordinary.

Thanks

Comment: Is the email using a separate Infopath view, maybe?

Comment: @teylyn Would a view appear in the notification email?  Thanks

Comment: Yes, but you need to take the proper steps. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/infopath/2007/01/17/e-mailing-a-custom-view/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emails can be set up to use a dedicated InfoPath view as the body contents. Check your pages/views.